# How do I communicate with a host USB device through Mac's Terminal?

Tags: terminal, network, usb, ssh, python

I have a Siglent SPD3303X-E power supply that I am attempting to interface with. I am running a Macbook Pro with OS Sonoma 14.3.1. I've read online about what SCPI commands to send to the power supply, that isn't the issue. What I'm trying to do is set up some form of live command prompt with the device, but I'm not sure if **screen**, **ssh**, or some other protocol is the right way to go. When I connect to it via USB or ethernet, I can confirm that the device is recognized by my computer with **lsusb**, but I'm unsure of how to connect to the device without writing a python script. I am able to write a python script but it seems time consuming to put it together or troubleshoot, so a "live" connection is preferred.

Comment: `lsusb` is more commonly found on Linux, it's not a recognised command on macOS. Please clarify exactly what you're doing to show the device is recognised on your MBP.

Comment: I installed `lsusb` with homebrew, but I also verified it with `ioreg -p IOUSB`

Comment: Ah! Apologies. I missed it when I checked `brew`

Comment: No worries! My question is more of 'what protocol should I use to connect to a USB device if I know the PID/VID?' do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: Try contacting Siglent’s Support Department. They would be able to tell you how to connect